# Can plugins in the Plugin Store require development versions of libraries via Composer?

Tags: plugin-development

I recently put together a basic [Constant Contact plugin](https://github.com/madebyraygun/constant-contact) for a project, and I'd like to clean it up and improve it for a public release. The problem is that it requires a development version of the Constant Contact SDK for compatibility with PHP 7+. I did this by adding a custom repository to the composer.json file pointing to the github repo, and then requiring the development branch.

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/constantcontact/php-sdk.git"
  }
],
"require": {
  "craftcms/cms": "^3.0.0-RC1",
  "constantcontact/constantcontact": "dev-development"
},
```

In order for this to work, I had to change the stability requirements in my main composer.json file:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable" : true,
```

It seems to me this would not be ideal for a plugin in the Plugin Store. Is packaging all of the dependencies up into a vendor subfolder within the project a better option?

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I should have used this alternate client: https://github.com/classy-org/constantcontact-php-client ... probably would have made things a lot easier.

Comment: Updated with the alternate API client and released in the plugin store! https://github.com/madebyraygun/constant-contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Plugin Store requires non-development dependencies in your `composer.json` file.

Comment: Great thanks, that clears things up! So I will give the alternate API client a try, since it's on Packagist and looks easy to implement.